# Is probability relative?

Tags: relativity, probability, relative-motion

Suppose you are as massive as earth and you are tumbling down space at a very high speed. You flip a coin. There is a probability function associated with the coin in motion. When it falls back in your hand, for you there is no more probability of the outcome. You know for certain if you got a head or a tail. But if I am observing your tumbling motion from a distance, the coin along with you is still flipping and so there is still a probability function associated to the coin and I do not know what the final outcome of the fall of the coin will be. So, isn't probability also relative to the observer?

Comment: Probability can rely on what is known now and the past; in that case it is both epistemological and relative; I'm not sure what the relevance here is to physics, it seems more appropriate to Phil.SE.

Comment: The probability you assign depends on the information you have. The two cases have different information so assign different probabilities. The details about being as massive as the earth are not relevant to the question.

Comment: I added "As massive as earth to imply that the coin will fall towards you instead of going in some other direction"

Comment: You might as well say one person spins a coin and sees the result is heads and so the probability of it being heads is 100%. Before the coin lands they would not know what the result is and so would assign a probability of 50% for heads.

Comment: I realise that you're drawing out a thought experiment to illustrate the question you're asking; however, the physics is not really integral to it - this is why I said it was philosophical rather than physical; if you were asking about the mathematics involved in studying this, then it would have been more appropriate to math.SE or math.overflow.

Comment: +1 Your question boils down to this: has the event happened, if you don't know the result? The conventional answer is yes, the event has happened and your knowledge about it is irrelevant. However, conventional answers are not always correct.

Comment: +1 How is this a bad question? It seems it shows effort, is interesting and quite on-topic.
Also, a "more random" event could be the decay of a single nucleus (as compared to the deterministic flip of a coin).

Answer (score 2):

No, and I'd say a simpler point of view is more useful:

- the experiment outcome is described by a probability distribution **before** the measurement;
- **after** the measurement, the outcome is a value (e.g., $+1$, heads).

$\to$ All you and a different observer might disagree about is whether the measurement has already taken place or not, not about what the probability distribution for the *expected* outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

My short answer is a claim:

**Measuring lead to the same probability of the result only under consideration of all influencing circumstances.**

This means, that the probability of a measurement could be different for different equipped observers. And I think I have a nice example for the above claim:

Take a cube with two sides in green, two in blue und two in yello. The probability for each color is 1/3th. Now give the cube to an experimentator who has [color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) for blue and green. The result of his experiment is 2/3th for blue and 1/3 for yellow.

Another example maybe a [beam splitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter). One measure single emitted photons and the probability for each beam behind the mirror would be 50%. Not knowing the wavelength for the photons, another observer will take emit photons at a different wavelength and the probability for the reflected photons will be unequal to the probability of the transmitted photons.

Your example is a little bit different. The probability for head or tail in both systems is 50 by 50%. The result of *each* measurement will be identical if you take in consideration the relative orientation of the “massive” observer to your orientation and converse your measurement of the coins position to the coins position of the “massive” observer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, I think it depends on how you define probability. Is it the "chance" of an occurrence based on how many times out of another (preferably, infinite) amount of times it will happen? Then, I'd say so. If you only talk about probability as the "chance" something will happen before it happens, then, of course, you can't measure probability after something happens.

Personally, I believe probability to be relative for the reason you described, and the reason I'm about to describe, but both are most certainly arguable and *relative* to every person, based on their definition of the term.

But I have a different question, I just felt like I shouldn't make a separate post about it. Say there's an omniscient being, like a god, which knows how hard I (in a normal state on Earth) am going to flip the coin. It knows the strength of every wind current and every Butterfly's wings flap. It can calculate the probability better than I can. Maybe, even to the point of being 100% certain in Heads having a probability of 1. But from my POV, the chances are still 0.5/0.5, assuming it always lands on either heads or tails. Doesn't that also make probability relative? It's somewhat similar to the Colourblind person described in @HolgerFiedler 's answer.